# Accessing ListView's data in exe program by external wrapper program

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a c++ exe program I do not own the source and I want to access some data which is in the ListView. Is there any way to do this?
(My best guess is using memory address but how to know the format of ListView)

[Image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88flt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access ListView data by sending LVM_ messages to it if it owns data.
Or if ListView is virtual, data is provided by LVN_ notifications by its parent window. Either way, you need to be in exe's address space, so you would have to inject own code (which can be achived by making that exe load your DLL, can be done by windows hooks or by CreateRemoteThread).
So, generally it is possible, but cumbersome.